# Is there a function in Python to expand data interval?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'record_id':["007",  "001", "009"], 
     'organizationid': ["b", "c", 'b'], 
     "timestamp_date": [["2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-11"], ["2020-05-11", "2020-05-11"], ['2020-05-13', '2020-05-13']]})

  record_id organizationid                                                            timestamp_date
0       007              b  [2020-05-11, 2020-05-11, 2020-05-11, 2020-05-11, 2020-05-11, 2020-05-11]
1       001              c                                                  [2020-05-11, 2020-05-11]
2       009              b                                                  [2020-05-13, 2020-05-13]
```

And I want to "enlace" the date, adding the dates there are missing between the first and last date (in this case I've added the 2020-05-12), transposing and adding the number of times this date appears in the row (or 0 if there is a day without this register), so it should be:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"2020-05-11": [6, 2, 0],
                  "2020-05-12": [0, 0, 0],
                  "2020-05-13": [0, 0, 2], 
     'organizationid': ["b", "c", 'b'], 
     "record_id": ["007", "001", "009"]})

   2020-05-11  2020-05-12  2020-05-13 organizationid record_id
0           6           0           0              b       007
1           2           0           0              c       001
2           0           0           2              b       009
```

I started trying with a column transposition, but after for "enlacing" the data I could not find how can I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `explode` with `groupby.count` and `unstack`

```
df = d.explode("timestamp_date").groupby(["record_id", "timestamp_date"])[
    "timestamp_date"
].count().unstack(1).fillna(0)

timestamp_date  2020-05-11  2020-05-13
record_id                             
001                    2.0         0.0
007                    6.0         0.0
009                    0.0         2.0
```

---

if you need to interpolate the dates, then you could do a Cartesian product of the date ranges.

we will have to create a dummy row to create the matrix and drop it with `.query`

```
s = d.explode('timepstamp_date')

s['timestamp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(s['timestamp_date'])

dates = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range(s["timestamp_date"].min(), s["timestamp_date"].max(), freq="D"),
    columns=["timestamp_date"],
)


s1 = pd.merge(s,dates,on=['timestamp_date'],how='outer').fillna('no_record')

df = pd.crosstab(s1.record_id, s1.timestamp_date).query('record_id != "no_record"')


print(df)

timestamp_date  2020-05-11  2020-05-12  2020-05-13
record_id                                         
001                      2           0           0
007                      6           0           0
009                      0           0           2
```

Comment: good one, i was actually thinking of using `reindex` .

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thanks why dont you add it as an answer, the more the merrier